# count() returning 1 when thousands of records

Tags: php, count, directory

this count is onyl returning 1, when there are thousands of records in this folder.

```
// TV Shows
$dir = 'G:/TV';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tv_shows WHERE title = '$file'");
        $checkcount = mysql_num_rows($check);

        if ($checkcount == 0) {

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO tv_shows (id, title) VALUES ('', '$file')");

        }

    }

    echo count($dir)." Records Traversed!<br/>";

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Table Structure: id, title

Folder Structure: Sub folders in the main one

```
 G:\TV
 G:\TV\24
 G:\TV\Family Guy
```

Comment: Hm, I think we need some more information to help you. Can you show us your folder structure and your database table layout please?

Comment: So there are thousands of records in the folder, and you're looping through each one of them and running 1 or possibly 2 queries for each file? That's going to absolutely wreck your database.

Comment: The value of $dir is string which is "G/TV";so it will return 1

Comment: ofcourse because $dir="G:/TV" and its one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `count()` on a folder. Try this one instead

```
// TV Shows
$dir = 'G:/TV';
$count = 0;
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        $count++;
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tv_shows WHERE title = '$file'");
        $checkcount = mysql_num_rows($check);

        if ($checkcount == 0) {

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO tv_shows (id, title) VALUES ('', '$file')");

        }

    }

    echo $count." Records Traversed!<br/>";

    closedir($handle);
}
```

> how about returning the number of new records inserted?

Check this out, just moved `$count++`

```
// TV Shows
$dir = 'G:/TV';
$count = 0;
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tv_shows WHERE title = '$file'");
        $checkcount = mysql_num_rows($check);

        if ($checkcount == 0) {
            $count++;
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO tv_shows (id, title) VALUES ('', '$file')");

        }

    }

    echo $count." Records Traversed!<br/>";

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: how about returning the number of new records inserted?

Comment: hmm i tried that before i asked and it didnt seem to work... il ltry again... it always returns 34 this way.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `count()` on a string, not an array.

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/GYVUrDvf).

Answer (score 0):

Also a good alternative to this is using the php glob function. 
`$dir_path = "/full/directory/path/";`
`$count = count(glob($dir_path . "*"));`

This will also optimize your code !!